# I can't login in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, login

I upgraded Ubuntu gnome to version 16.04 from 15.10 using the update manager.
I think I selected new (probably wrong) parameters with loging in, because when I boot, I see:

The loading sign

then lines of code

at the bottom of the screen, : login (name of my computer):_

I tried to type my password that I used in the previous version, but I can't see that I'm typing, and nothing happens.
How can I access the normal login screen?